# How to read depedency version from properties file

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have one maven project. I want to externalise maven dependancy version to external property file. 
I tried with property file plugin I is not reading property file.

config.properties

```
springframework.version=4.2.5.RELEASE
```

POm.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.estuate.test</groupId>
<artifactId>testPom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>config.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

still I am gettting error message as

```
build.plugins.plugin[org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin].dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-core:jar must be a valid version but is '${springframework.version}'
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Why not using the most recent version of the [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) which 1.0.0 ?

Comment: I didn't understand the solution. I have only one pom.xml file and I don't have any parent maven  project or module module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a plugin with a custom execution, like you do, then you must realise that it only executes in the phases you specify. You specify **pre-clean** phase, which is part of the **clean** lifecycle, and not part of the **build** lifecycle.

Maven is composed of lifecycles, which execute up to a given phase. A command of `mvn compile` actually means run the **build** lifecycle all phases up to and including the **compile** phase.

Two of the standard lifecycles are (not complete list):

```
clean :: pre-clean -> clean -> post-clean

build :: validate -> compile -> test -> package -> verify -> install -> deploy
```

The dependencies specified are probably used by the standard plugins for the **compile** phase, so the properties needs to be available at that time.

When you state the pre-clean phase, the properties are available when you execute `mvn clean`.

For the properties to be available at **compile** phase, you should probably bind to the **validate** phase instead.

Although very verbose, there is actually quite a few hints running in debug mode with `mvn -X`, but it may be too much to comprehend at first.

Some more information about maven lifecycles here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: I tried with phase : validate and Compile. But it not working out

Comment: I am trying with this but getting same issue. @SantoshkumarKalasa is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

you can use maven properties plugin which is one of the suggested way to read property files in maven projects. below is the plugin details

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <files>
                    <file>Versions.properties</file>
                  </files>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Version.properties file looks like

```
springframework.version=4.2.5.RELEASE
```

Comment: Well, that is actually what he is trying.. same plugin same goals. You are missing his problem, which is the phase he binds to.

Comment: yes Nielsen correct, i had changed the execution phase that was the difference.

Comment: Its not working out

Comment: Rajesh wat u did that it worked u changed the execution phase from?

Answer (score -1):

I think . 
You should assign a Spring version to the springframework.version statement.
For example

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.1-REALESE</version>
     </dependency>
```

then the other dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...framework...</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-...</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```